# merger the csv data with php?

Tags: php

There are many `CSV` file like the following:`a.csv`, `b.csv`, `aab.csv` etc.

They hold the same column and header. Now I want to put all the csv data into `whole.csv`. With only one header. How can I do it?

`a.csv` data:

```
header1 title post.....

test   who  posand
```

`b.csv` data:

```
header1 title post.....

head   she  pnow
```

etc .....

The whole.csv will contain all the csv data.
eg:

```
header1 title post.....

head   she  pnow
test   who  posand
```

I tried the following code.but not get I want to:

```
$csvs = glob("*.csv");

foreach($csvs as $csv) {
  $row = 1;
  if (($handle = fopen($csv, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
      $fp = fopen("whole.csv", 'w');
      fputcsv($fp, $data);
      $row++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
  }
}
```

I have put all CSV files in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

For every input csv file you are opening the resultant csv file in write mode:

```
$fp = fopen("whole.csv", 'w');
```

which wipes the content of the `whole.csv`!!

You need to open the `whole.csv` file just once outside the loop and keep writing into it.

```
$csvs = glob("*.csv");
$fp   = fopen("whole.csv", 'w');

foreach($csvs as $csv) {
  $row = 1;
  if (($handle = fopen($csv, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
      fputcsv($fp, $data);
      $row++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
  }
}
```

Comment: are there some bug in the code. it shows Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded i

Comment: i only test it with only four csv files.

Comment: How many lines are inside those csv files? What are their size?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `file_put_contents`.

You would open each CSV file, then use `file_put_contents` passing `whole.csv` as the `$filename` parameter, the file handle as the `$data` parameter and use the `FILE_APPEND` flag to tell it to append the contents instead of overwriting.